Websocket error Unexpected server response: 403 {}
It’s been several days now that I’m stuck and I have no more idea.
I deploy my application on a kubernetes pod and a active mq queue on another pod.
My goal is to consume the messages from the MQ queue but I have this error : Websocket error Unexpected server response: 403 {}
I deployed a Activemq in local and I did tests with the same image as on the pod and I have no worries.
For reasons of confidentiality I can not share too much information but here is a part of the description of my pod :
Name:                 application-name-7599d65cb7-78nk9
Namespace:            name
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Start Time:           Mon, 29 Jul 2024 07:10:50 +0200
Labels:               app.kubernetes.io/instance=application-name
                      app.kubernetes.io/name=application-name
                    
Annotations:          CapacityProvisioned: 1vCPU 3GB
                      Logging: LoggingEnabled
                      data-ingest.dynatrace.com/injected: true
                      dynakube.dynatrace.com/injected: true
                      oneagent.dynatrace.com/injected: true
Status:               Running
IP:                   xx.xx.xx.xx
IPs:
  IP:           xx.xx.xx.xx
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/application-name-7599d65cb7
Init Containers:
  install-oneagent:
    Container ID:  containerd://xxxxxxxx
    Image:         docker.io/dynatrace/dynatrace-operator:v0.9.0
    Image ID:      docker.io/dynatrace/dynatrace-operator@sha256:xxxxxxxx
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      init
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 29 Jul 2024 07:10:56 +0200
      Finished:     Mon, 29 Jul 2024 07:10:56 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      CONTAINERS_COUNT:      1
      FAILURE_POLICY:        silent
      K8S_PODNAME:           application-name-7599d65cb7-78nk9 (v1:metadata.name)
      K8S_PODUID:             (v1:metadata.uid)
      K8S_BASEPODNAME:       application-name-7599d65cb7
      K8S_CLUSTER_ID:        xxxxxxxxxxx
      K8S_NAMESPACE:         name (v1:metadata.namespace)
      K8S_NODE_NAME:          (v1:spec.nodeName)
      FLAVOR:
      TECHNOLOGIES:          all
      INSTALLPATH:           /opt/dynatrace/oneagent-paas
      INSTALLER_URL:
      MODE:                  installer
      ONEAGENT_INJECTED:     true
      CONTAINER_1_NAME:      application-name
      CONTAINER_1_IMAGE:     apache/activemq-classic:6.1.1
      DT_WORKLOAD_KIND:      Deployment
      DT_WORKLOAD_NAME:      application-name
      DATA_INGEST_INJECTED:  true
Containers:
  application-name:
    Container ID:   containerd://xxxxxxx
    Image:          apache/activemq-classic:6.1.1
    Ports:          61616/TCP, 8161/TCP, 61614/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running

In my app I use this configuration :
"stomp": {
                "enabled": true,
                "brokerURL": "ws://application-name-7599d65cb7-78nk9:61614",
                "connectHeaders": {
                    "login": "admin",
                    "password": "admin"
                },
                "reconnectDelay": 5000,
                "heartbeatIncoming": 5000,
                "heartbeatOutgoing": 5000
            }

If someone has an idea .. Thank you !

Refer to this Stack Link which might be helpful to resolve your issue
